# LaTeX: Unbalance imakeidx

Tags: positioning, indexing, imakeidx, idxlayout

My problem is: I have a huge index and I don't want to balance it. 
 I have 12 indices and use this package: `\usepackage[noautomatic, nonewpage]{imakeidx}`.  See picture attached to understand what I try to do. [image: unbalance last column, so it does not break where it does right now!]
I've tried it with `\usepackage[unbalanced]{idxlayout}` but with partial success (every index starts on a new page). Also tried it with `Original` option but that puts every index on new page and I don't want that.  *Sorry, I cannot post the whole code.* 
This is how I add my indices:

```
\makeindex[name=FeintoolNorm,title=Stichwortverzeichnis, columns=2]
```

This is very frustrating, because people have the opposite problem which I cannot reproduce :-\ 
 If you need more information, please let me know since I don't know where the problem is, I don't know what you need to know.

---

EDIT: Uploaded an MWE: [mwe_NormOrdner.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8DpN9H9EfbPQV9fYTVDMS1hWGM)
Extract the zip and run `Norm_Erstellen.bat`. If it doesn't work, adjust the paths to `makeindex.exe` and `pdflatex.exe` in this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you didn't provide code it is quite unclear what definition for the index you are using. But you can try to patch it to use multicols* instead of multicols:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\theindex{\begin{multicols}}{\begin{multicols*}}{}{\fail}
\xpatchcmd\endtheindex{\end{multicols}}{\end{multicols*}}{}{\fail}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
a\index{a}\index{b}\index{c}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ulrike, vielen Dank für die Antwort. 
Unfortunately the patched multicols forces each index to start on a new page - again. 
What do you need to know (*definitions for the index*)?  
My document is created with the help of Excel and VBA. Then I need a separate batch file to make the multiple indices work (TeXstudio does not a good job at that). 
What I do here is I import 229 PDF docs and create an index to easier find the content. My index consists of text from Excel and some complicated macro-stuff in LaTeX.
Please let me know what you need to know! **Any** help/input is appreciated!

Comment: If you have more than one index than you probably need the patch only before the last one. And what I need should be obvious: some example to test the issue and possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike! That did the trick! :-)
*I didn't want to post the code, becaues it is spread over 5 files (not to mention the 229 pdf files) which 4 of them are generated automatically and making an MWE would have been nearly impossible - I just wanted to focus on the main "issue".*

Comment: Making a MWE is not impossible and imho wouldn't take so much time. After all you only want to show a problem with two indices.  So the preamble, some \index commands and two \printindex should be enough.

Comment: No, it's truly not impossible - it only took me 2 hours to make one and get it to work without Excel and reveling sensitive data. Please see first post for zip file.