# Weird index sorting display using tufte-book

Tags: indexing, tufte

I am using `tufte-book` for creating the document and `makeidx` for creating the index. The three column index generates correctly, but it displays it in a weird manner. Instead of alphabetical entries being in the first column, filling it and then moving to the next column, it is spreading entries over all three columns. And only when the third column is full, it moves the entries to the first column. Ideally it should be filling the first column first then move to the next one.

[image]

It makes index very hard to read. The second image shows how it should be. Any ideas of how to sort this?

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{tufte-book}

\renewcommand\allcapsspacing[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15}#1}}
\renewcommand\smallcapsspacing[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10}#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\indexname{Subject Index}
\lipsum{}
\index{Solutions!neutral}
\index{Adiabatic}
\index{chemistry}
\index{Solutions!basic}
\index{Solutions!acidic}
\index{Adiabatic}
\index{chemistry}
\index{approximation}
\index{approximation!one-electron}
\index{approximation}
\index{Baryons}
\index{Baryons!charge}
\index{Ammonia}
\index{Ammonia!in electric field}
\index{Ammonia!in reaction}
\index{Ammonia!gas}
\index{Atom!states}


\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but basically the same issue: [LaTeX: Unbalance imakeidx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354152/82917). Of course you are using `makeidx` and not `imakeidx` but both the underlying problem and the solution are the same.

Comment: Thanks! the `xpatch` hack sorted it out.